# dependency conflict -- node

Tags: node.js, npm

this is my first time posting a question on stack overflow so please go easy on me :)

i am trying to spin up an old project and am running into some dependency conflicts and am quite lost. when i first run npm install i get a couple errors — see below.

```
 code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-webpack-workflow@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@2.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@2.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!   dev css-loader@"2.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

i run the command(s) they recommend and get a litany of warnings that i need to update old dependencies (which i expected), so i try and run npm update and the initial error (photo above) happens again.

i then read through [this post](http://code%20ERESOLVE%20npm%20ERR!%20ERESOLVE%20unable%20to%20resolve%20dependency%20tree%20npm%20ERR!%20npm%20ERR!%20While%20resolving:%20angular-webpack-workflow@1.1.0%20npm%20ERR!%20Found:%20webpack@2.7.0%20npm%20ERR!%20node_modules/webpack%20npm%20ERR!%20%20%20dev%20webpack@%22%5E2.2.0%22%20from%20the%20root%20project%20npm%20ERR!%20npm%20ERR!%20Could%20not%20resolve%20dependency:%20npm%20ERR!%20peer%20webpack@%22%5E4.0.0%22%20from%20css-loader@2.1.1%20npm%20ERR!%20node_modules/css-loader%20npm%20ERR!%20%20%20dev%20css-loader@%222.1.1%22%20from%20the%20root%20project%20npm%20ERR!%20npm%20ERR!%20Fix%20the%20upstream%20dependency%20conflict,%20or%20retry%20npm%20ERR!%20this%20command%20with%20--force,%20or%20--legacy-peer-deps%20npm%20ERR!%20to%20accept%20an%20incorrect%20(and%20potentially%20broken)%20dependency%20resolution.) which has very similar issues but to be honest, i think i'm getting incredibly confused.

i'm getting **mad** tripped up on this so any help will be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the commands (I believe it's npm install) and packages.json content as well?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, you are seeing a dependency conflict between     `css-loader@^2.1.1"` and `webpack@^2.7.0`. I was able to replicate this problem in `npm@7` which has stricter dependency checking than previous versions of `npm`. As a workaround run `npm install` with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag and it will use the older, less-strict peer dependency resolution.

Once you have your project installed and working, it would be a very good idea to update your dependencies. I hope you have good tests. `css-loader` is (at the time of this writing) at version 5.1.1. The last 2.x release was about 2 years ago. And `webpack` is currently at version 5.24.2. The last 2.x release for webpack was about 4 years ago.

Comment: hi! thanks for actually trying to explain it to me vs just force feeding answers :)

so i ran `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and that's when i received a whole list of warnings that all of my dependencies were super old (which i knew they would be). when i ran `npm update` i received the same initial error about my webpack and css-loader. 

is there a different command i should use? or should i be updating them

Comment: I would try `npm uninstall --save-dev css-loader webpack` to uninstall the dependencies entirely. Then reinstall them with `npm install --save-dev css-loader webpack`. Hopefully, there won't be any dependency conflict with the latest versions, but if so, try `--legacy-peer-deps` again. And, of course, stuff might break with the newer version. Hopefully you have good tests or else your app is fairly simple and can be tested manually.

Comment: word, i'll give it a go. thank you again so much.  fairly simple app is an understatement. :)